# How to force NPM to use a locally hosted registry

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When you install a node module, NPM gets the package from the default registry:

```
https://registry.npmjs.org
```

My company is hosting its own node registry and I want use it. How can I force NPM to use this local registry.

**I don't want to use `npm install --registry` option.**

Is there a way to make all the users on a specific machine to use this internal registry?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What worked for me was, I ran following command :

```
npm config set registry PATH_TO_YOUR_LOCAL_REGISTRY
```

Another option is to create a .`NPMRC` file and put it into your project root directory. As mentioned in this [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) project specific npmrc file will take the highest priority & it will override other configuration. In this file just update the registry.

**In npmrc file, add following:**

```
registry = "https://path to local registry"
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use the `--registry` option–you can just set the `package.json` to point to your internal repository [0]:

Set `"private": true` in your `package.json` to prevent your package from being published, and set:

```
"publishConfig": {
   "registry": "http://my-internal-registry.local"
}
```

to force it to be published only to your internal registry.

[0] https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry#i-dont-want-my-package-published-in-the-official-registry-its-private

Comment: Thank for your answer. I added both `private` & `publishConfig` options. But still system is trying to use `registry.npmjs.org ` I am getting following error `584 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/classnames
585 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443`